# Mocha 5.1.1 is not testing all files

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js

I upgraded mocha from `^2.2.5` to `5.1.1` in my Angular JS project. I have 11550 test cases in my application, all of which were successful before the upgrade. However, after upgrading Mocha, I'm getting irregular outputs while running grunt test such as

- Firefox 60.0.0 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 6132 of 11550 (skipped 86) SUCCESS (3 mins 13.945 secs / 16.863 secs)
  TOTAL: 6132 SUCCESS
- Firefox 60.0.0 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 868 of 11550 (skipped 9) SUCCESS (35.564 secs / 3.799 secs)
  TOTAL: 868 SUCCESS
- Firefox 60.0.0 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 951 of 11550 (3 FAILED) (skipped 9) (32.092 secs / 3.229 secs)
  TOTAL: 3 FAILED, 948 SUCCESS

1) "before each" hook
     Testing the homePageService functionality

2) "after each" hook

```
 currentSpec is null
```

module.$$cleanup@http://localhost:8100/base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?861c27a0d62d5f7beed79cd1b40b44f0560b2eb5:2992:9
module.$$afterEach@http://localhost:8100/base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?861c27a0d62d5f7beed79cd1b40b44f0560b2eb5:2987:7

3) "after each" hook for "To test submitZip   method"

```
 currentSpec is null
```

module.$$cleanup@http://localhost:8100/base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?861c27a0d62d5f7beed79cd1b40b44f0560b2eb5:2992:9
module.$$afterEach@http://localhost:8100/base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?861c27a0d62d5f7beed79cd1b40b44f0560b2eb5:2987:7

Do note that for the first two times I ran test, I wasn't getting any logs on the NPM console for failed tests, which of course was because the tests were passing, although after ignoring many TCs.

Angular CLI: 6.0.1
Node: 9.4.0
NPM: 5.6.0
OS: win32 x64